# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim' matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a plot for double integral using python, matplotlib.
X and Y ranges are defined and Z is the double integral of X and Y.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})

def function_I(x, y):
    return np.sin(x)*np.cos(y/5)

#Make data
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = scipy.integrate.dblquad(function_I, -5, 5, -5, 5)

# plot the surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

line

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
```

gives

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

some similar question provided solutions related to .shape and .reshape? Doesn't make a whole lot sense. Any comments appreciated!

Comment: Will you please provide the full error traceback, in the question?

Comment: Check the documentation for `scipy.integrate.dblquad`. It returns more than an array. I found this page by copy/pasting "scipy.integrate.dblquad" into google and clicking on the first result: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html

Comment: Check the `type` of the 3 arguments, `X`, `Y`, `Z`. Before searching the web or asking us, you should have a clear idea of what each of the variables is.

Comment: Try `ax.plot_surface(X, Y, np.array(Z))`

Comment: @richardec that won't work, Z is a tuple of an array and a scalar

Comment: Isn't `Z` a tuple of a `float` and `float`, @PaulH? `Returns:  y: float, abserr: float`

Comment: Thx for the comments,  ```ans, err = scipy.integrate.dblquad(function_I(X,Y), -5, 5, -5, 5)``` is indeed more accurate, still trying to figure this out...

Comment: ```function_I = lambda y, x: np.sin(x)*np.cos(y/5)``` and ```ans, err = scipy.integrate.dblquad(function_I, -5, 5, -5, 5)``` looks like this part solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dblquad(function_I, -5, 5, -5, 5)` calculates the integral of one complete area, so resulting in a single value.

The following approach intents to calculate the integral for each little patch between successive coordinates.  And then draw a surface using the mean XY position of each patch.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

def function_I(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) * np.cos(y / 5)

# Make data
X = np.linspace(-5, 5, 41)
Y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 41)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = np.zeros_like(X)
for i in range(1, X.shape[0]):
    for j in range(1, X.shape[1]):
        Z[i, j], _ = dblquad(function_I, X[i - 1, j - 1], X[i, j], Y[i - 1, j - 1], Y[i, j])

# plot the surface
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
ax.plot_surface((X[:-1, :-1] + X[1:, 1:]) / 2, (Y[:-1, :-1] + Y[1:, 1:]) / 2, Z[1:, 1:])

plt.show()
```

[image: plot_surface of dblquad]